# How to efficiently Shard a MongoDb collections that already has millions of documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, sharding

I have a collection named order_error. Which has over 60 million documents. Today I was trying to shard it. I have 3 replica sets. Initially, no issues were there. The balancer was distributing the chunks among the clusters. But eventually, it has started to consume all Ram space and after all swap space too. Now everything is unresponsive. We can't follow this procedure in production. We need a better solution for that. How can I do the sharding in a better way?
If someone could help me with that please let me know

Comment: it's a hint to increase ram? Btw, during initial replication, you will definitely use more ram+cpu.

Comment: I tried with increasing RAM. But that didn't help much. The process is really slow. What about creating an empty collection, Shard it and exporting all documents to that collection?
So it will split while inserting. Isn't it?
@SomeoneSpecial

Comment: u can try. But 60 million documents, you should give it time.. it will take many hours even if you do insertOne() x 60 million times. It's not instant

Comment: @JithinVariyar i think that is your best bet, depending on how many and how large your indexes are you can probably insert 60milion documents in less than 2hours.

i think your actual bottleneck in this approach will be to paginate over the data, if you have an easy way to do it I think it's the safer approach.

Comment: Perhaps you selected a poor shard-key.

Answer (score 0):

When you insert documents into an empty collection, then initially all date will be written to the [primary shard](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-shards/#primary-shard), so it will not solve your issue.

But you can use [sh.splitAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.splitAt/#mongodb-method-sh.splitAt) on empty collection to pre-split the it.

Note, even if the collection is empty it will take some time till chunks are distributed over all shards! When you split a chunk, then it still remains on the current shard. Check with `db.collection.getShardDistribution()` whether chunks are evenly distributed.